# Adding more than one button to navigation bar using smart GWT mobile

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, mobile-application

[image: navigation bar]

hello i have a **navigation bar** that is using smart GWT mobile, where i have added log out as the right button i need to add one more *button on the right* , please help i tried adding child it doesnt seem to work please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set css style property `float: right` on the button. First add a style class name to Button and then define the css rules in CSS file as -

```
.button-style{
    float: right;
}
```